# Get Specfic response from MySql in jQuery AJAX Success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Well i have this ajax code which will return the result from MySql in Success block.

```
$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url:"index.php",
   success: function(data){
            alert(data);                
        }
});
```

My Query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
$rs=parent::_executeQuery($sql);
$rs=parent::getAll($rs);
print_r($rs);
return $rs
```

My Response Array in alert of Success AJAX

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [section_id] => 5
            [version] => 1
            [section_name] => Crop Details
            [id] => 5
            [document_name] => Site Survey
            [document_master_id] => 1
            [document_section_id] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (           
            [section_id] => 28
            [version] => 1
            [section_name] => Vegetative Report           
            [id] => 6
            [document_name] => Site Survey
            [document_master_id] => 1
            [document_section_id] => 28
        )

)
```

I want to get only **section_name** and **document_name** from the result so that i can append these two values to my list.

Comment: Use `json_encode()` to return the response as JSON, so can parse it in Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't return the response using `print_r()`, use `json_encode()`:

```
echo json_encode($rs);
```

Then in the Javascript, you can do:

```
$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url:"index.php",
   dataType: 'json'
   success: function(data){
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            console.log(data[i].section_name, data[i].document_name);          
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Make sure the PHP script doesn't output anything other than this `echo` statement. Go to the Network tab to see the full response, so you can see if there's something else being echoed.

Comment: it worked. I had <!doctype html> at the top, which i din't observed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

change your select query with

```
$sql = "SELECT section_name,document_name FROM tablename";
```

Comment: Thanks. But i have joined multiple tables. i could not have this query. I need to filter it in ajax itself.

Comment: Why couldn't you have this query?  All this query is doing is filtering out to only have the values you want.

Comment: Then i wouldnt have asked this question

Comment: provide your query and let others decide way for you.

Comment: Even if he changes the query, he still has the issue of how to get the data in Javascript. `print_r()` output is not designed to be parsed.

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
$rs=parent::_executeQuery($sql);
$rs=parent::getAll($rs);

return json_encode($rs);
```

index.php

```
$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url:"index.php",
   success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        var data = JSON.parse(data);
        /* you can use $.each() function here  */                
    }
});
```

Comment: its giving me Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token S

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
$rs=parent::_executeQuery($sql);
$rs=parent::getAll($rs);
$resp = array();
foreach( $rs as $each ){
    $resp[]['section_name'] = $each['section_name'];
    $resp[]['document_name'] = $each['document_name'];
}
return json_encode($resp);
```

Access JSON response like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].section_name, data[i].document_name);          
}
```