# Looping throught json

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, laravel

I'm writing ajax post request. The problem is that i don't know how to loop throught json. on success i got this function:

```
.done(function ( data ) {
  $('#records').append(data);
});
```

And it prints content into my #records like this:

```
0: {id: 1, user_id: 1, title: "first", created_at: "2015-05-15 06:50:21",…}
1: {id: 2, user_id: 2, title: "second", created_at: "2015-05-15 06:50:38",…}
2: {id: 3, user_id: 3, title: "third", created_at: "2015-05-15 06:50:41",…}
3: {id: 4, user_id: 4, title: "fourth", created_at: "2015-05-15 06:50:45",…}
```

How do i loop throught id's and pick it's content (1,2,3,4)?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Find answer here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342371/jquery-loop-on-json-data-using-each

you need to use $.each() function or check in jquery docs

Comment: You should probably look at this thread 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27478808/get-specfic-response-from-mysql-in-jquery-ajax-success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.done(function ( data ) {
    $.each(data, function(item) {
        $('#records').append(item.id);
    });
```

});

Comment: sure just did, this uses jQuery to loop through the JSON array.  Each item will be represented as "item" so item will have all it's attributes available, item.id, item.title etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
.done(function ( data ) {
  //We declare the target element in a variable for better perfs
  var target = $('#records');
  //We loop in the returned array
  data.forEach(function(elt) {
     //Here the elt variable represents an item of your JSON array
     //You can access to item properties with the . (ex : elt.id, elt.title,...)
     target.append("<h2>"+elt.title+"</h2>");
  });  
});
```

[`forEach` function reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)